# unable to get title bar and navigation button items

Tags: iphone, objective-c, titlebar

I have added a new file to my project in that i am creating the screens programatically and i used following code to create a grouped table view with a title bar & 2 buttons on title bar, but its creating only grouped table but not title bar y it is so, can  any one help me thanx in advance

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Add Item";
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                              target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)] autorelease];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                               target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];



    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"+"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(Add)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

[journeylist.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Journey List" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"listIcon-H.png"] tag:1];
journeylist.navigationItem.title =@"Journey List";

NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:journeylist,appstore,settings,about,nil];
self.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to present it like this.

```
SomeViewController *controller = [[SomeViewController alloc]
                                initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                             initWithRootViewController:controller];
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
[controller release];
```

**Edit**

When you are showing that controller with table view you have to frist add it to a navigation controller in order to show the navigation bar.

Comment: @robin Has your answer ended up on the wrong question? You and @Rani seem to be answering the same thing but not the question above. Or am I being stupid?

Comment: @dave the code of @kiran is correct. that is how you create buttons on the navigation bar. But he is not seeing the navigation bar because he has to add the controller in a navigation controller first. I have the same issue but got the work done by using this code.

Comment: @robin SomeViewController should be of type UIViewController ? because i am getting error on these lines    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.isAddingNewEntry = YES;
    controller.isConvertingToTimeEntry = NO;  ERROR: delegate not found for object of type UIViewController

Comment: sorry kiran i have pasted the code that i was using for my clients app check the edited code. i was using those variables to display something in that view controller

Comment: @robin  i i have tried ur code robin but i am unable to see title bar,is we need to set any delegates?

Comment: no you don't have to. @kiran can you tell me one thing are you using view controller with uitoolbar or navigation bar to show the title.

Comment: have u simulated it or added the navigationbar in the xib.

Answer (score 0):

Your table frame is `CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415)` so top left, you'll need to leave room for the title bar say `CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 415)`.